# Is there an RTOS for normal PCs?

Tags: operating-system, rtos

Is there an RTOS that can be run on a normal PC?

Where normal means something like a laptop with an intel i3 processor and 4 GB RAM.

If no such system exists, is it possible to make one?

Comment: Yes. There are a number of them. Try using a search engine with something like "x86 realtime OS". And since you're asking then, no, it's not possible to make one.

Comment: Since in a real-time system, the RTOS is normally an intrinsic part of the programming solution rather than just a "platform", I suggest that this was inappropriately closed.  It comes under the *"software tools commonly used by programmers"*.  Anyhow the answer is that you need an RTOS that targets x86 and ideally for which there is board-support for standard PC hardware.  There are many; eCos and QNX for example.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [QNX](http://www.qnx.com).  (Filler text to get at least 30 characters.)